# issue with pivot control windows phone 10?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-10

I am working on a windows 10 application that needs a custom type of control for which i need the following behaviors, Started of with pivot control in windows phone 10.

I need two sections for the pivot like one section above the header and one section below the header.

The Above section will have some image and the below section has a collection which can be scrolled.

When I swipe up on the screen,it should hide the section above the header. and when again swiped up on the below section,the contents below the header should be scrolled(pivot is locked and the below contents should scroll).

When i scroll down if there is no items to scroll below the header,then header and the contents above the header should come down(coming to initial stage when the page loaded).

When i swipe right/left,the pivot and the contents below and above the pivot should change.

I have my code shared 
here..

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vd1vahxdj28qf5g/CustomPivot.zip?dl=0

Code Samples
View MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="PivotControl.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PivotControl"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomPivotStyle" TargetType="Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_ViewChanged"  
                                      VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" 
                                      HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" 
                                      VerticalSnapPointsType="None"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="0,-300,0,0">
                                    <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform >
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0" />
                                    </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ItemsPresenter>
                                <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,300,0,0">
                                    <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0" />
                                    </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                </PivotHeaderPanel>

                            </PivotPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate">
        <Grid Height="110" Width="500" Margin="0,0,0,10" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="110" Height="110">
                <Image Source="{Binding Property3}" Height="110" Width="110"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property2}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}" d:IsLocked="True">
    <Pivot Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MainPivot" Style="{StaticResource CustomPivotStyle}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" d:IsLocked="True" >
        <Pivot.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Pivot.RenderTransform>
        <Pivot.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.TitleTemplate>
        <PivotItem Header="PivotItem 0"  Background="{x:Null}" d:IsLocked="True">
            <Grid d:IsLocked="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF7171C3" Stroke="Black" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                <ListView Height="430" Loaded="listView_Loaded"  x:Name="listView0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Margin="19,12,19,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" d:IsLocked="True" />
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="PivotItem 1" Background="{x:Null}" d:IsLocked="True">
            <Grid d:IsLocked="True" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FFB2209E" Stroke="Black" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                <ListView Height="430" Loaded="listView1_Loaded" x:Name="listView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Margin="19,12,19,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" d:IsLocked="True"/>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="PivotItem 2" Background="{x:Null}" d:IsLocked="True">
            <Grid d:IsLocked="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF29BF4B" Stroke="Black" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                <ListView Height="430" Loaded="listView2_Loaded" x:Name="listView2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Margin="19,12,19,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2" d:IsLocked="True"/>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>

    <!--<Grid ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta" Background="Transparent" x:Name="OverlayGrid" ManipulationMode="TranslateY"/>-->
</Grid>
```

MainPage.Xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace PivotControl
  {

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ScrollViewerView FinalView;
    double[] ar = new double[2];
    bool isUp, isDown;
    double initialValue = 0, currentValue;
    private ScrollViewerView defaultValue;
    private ListView myViewwer;
    private List<ScrollViewer> ViewwerList = new List<ScrollViewer>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent(); //
    }



    private void listView1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myViewwer = (sender as ListView);
        var data = myViewwer.FindChild<ScrollViewer>();


        data.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        data.ViewChanged += Data_ViewChanged;
        ViewwerList.Add(data);
    }

    private void listView2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myViewwer = (sender as ListView);
        var data = myViewwer.FindChild<ScrollViewer>();
        data.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;


        data.ViewChanged += Data_ViewChanged;
        ViewwerList.Add(data);
    }






    ScrollViewer mainScrollViewer;
    private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mainScrollViewer == null)
            mainScrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        currentValue = (sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset;


        var maxVerticalOffset = mainScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;

        Debug.WriteLine(currentValue + "  ***" + initialValue + "  c-1  " + (initialValue - currentValue));
        if (initialValue - currentValue < 0 && !isUp)
        {
            //AnimateUp.Begin();
            mainScrollViewer.ViewChanged -= ScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
            (sender as ScrollViewer).ChangeView((sender as ScrollViewer).HorizontalOffset, 300, 1);
            isUp = true;
            isDown = false;

            mainScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
            //mainScrollViewer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            //mainScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
            // mainScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
            foreach (var item in ViewwerList)
            {
                item.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
                //item.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
            }
            //initialValue = 250;
        }
        else if (initialValue - currentValue > 10 && !isDown)
        {
            //  AnimateDown.Begin();


            //(sender as ScrollViewer).ChangeView((sender as ScrollViewer).HorizontalOffset, 0, 1);
            isUp = false;
            isDown = true;
            mainScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
            mainScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
            //  mainScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
            foreach (var item in ViewwerList)
            {
                item.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
                //item.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;

            }
        }
        initialValue = currentValue;


    }

    private void listView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myViewwer = (sender as ListView);
        var data = myViewwer.FindChild<ScrollViewer>();
        data.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        //data.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
        data.ViewChanged += Data_ViewChanged;
        ViewwerList.Add(data);
    }


    }

}
```

}

Any helps appreciated.

Comment: can you post samples of your code here. no one is going to download a 3 mb file, unzip, try to figure out everything, then come back to stackoverflow and tell you, " hey this is what you should change" too much of a struggle don't you think?

Comment: Can we write different xaml views for each pivotItem and bind different classes to each different pivot Item